# Running ReactJS build on wpengine, where wordpress code is placed

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, routes, wpengine

I am trying to run my ReactJS build on [wp engine](https://wpengine.com/) hosting, where my WordPress site is already residing. I have placed my ReactJS build on the root along with other folders such as wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes.

My ReactJS build is placed in a folder named calculator. My React App URL looks like this **http://xyz.blahblah.com/calculator/** When I launch this URL, It works normally in the flow but I am unable to open any of my React Route directly from the web browser.

When I try to open any other route directly such as **http://xyz.blahblah.com/calculator/recomendations** It takes me to the WordPress site page not found page. How to fix this? So that I can open any route of my ReactJS App.

Below is my React App routing code:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/calculator">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={QuestionsWrapper} />
        <Route path="/recomendations" component={Recomendations} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```